# Parameterization of the curve by arc length

Tags: differential-geometry

Can anyone tell me how do I calculate the length of this curve :
$\rho = \sin^3(\frac{t}{3})$?

$\alpha = \cos(t)\sin^3(\frac{t}{3}), \sin(t)\sin^3(\frac{t}{3})$

I need to find a parametrization by arc length, and I got stuck on the integral.

Comment: Is $\alpha$ the curve? If so, what is $\rho$? Finally, could you please show us the integral that you're stuck with? Sorry for throwing so many questions at you. :)

Comment: Yes, &alpha; is the curve. Range of t is R. L = 1/2t - 3/4sin(2t/3). Now the problem is that the solution of the integral is very complicated, and by that I mean that I don't know how to find what t equals to.

Comment: So what is the integral you're trying to do?

Comment: Why do you need a parametrization by arclength if all you want is the length of the curve? Unless the question is explicitly to parametrize by arclength, one can always get around such things in differential geometry by using the chain rule (correctly). Did the problem not tell you $0\le t\le T$ for some value of $T$? [If you want a closed curve, you should be able to figure out the smallest value of $T$ that will work.]

Comment: Do you possibly mean that you want the *natural*,  or intrinsic, equation? That is, one that is independent of any coordinate system.